# passing value to remote ant target

Tags: ant

I have two ant files say **antFile1.xml** and **antFile2.xml** on windows and linux machine respectively.

**antFile1.xml**

```
<target name="executeOnLinux">
        <sshexec 
            host="${remote.host.ip}" 
            username="${remote.user.id}" 
            password="${remote.user.ssh.password}" 
            command="ant -f antFile2.xml 'linuxAntTarget'"
            trust="true"/>
</target>
```

**antFile2.xml**

```
<target name="linuxAntTarget">
        <input message="Enter application edition number" addproperty="editionNo"/> 
        <echo message="${editionNo}"/>
</target>
```

When I execute the the target named "**executeOnLinux**" from **antFile1.xml** from my, it connects to the linux machine and starts executing the "**linuxAntTarget**" from **antFile2.xml** file. But, as soon as it reaches to the the point where user input is required keeps waiting since I am not able to pass the input. My question is how can I pass the value to it? Is this even possible or there is any other better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Since Ant 1.9.4, the [sshexec](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) task provides a `useSystemIn` attribute:

> Whether to pass the current standard input to the remote process, defaults to false

You may also try the `input` attribute from the same task:

> A file from which the executed command's standard input is taken. This attribute is mutually exclusive with the inputstring and inputproperty attributes.
>   When executing more than one command via commandResource, input will be read for each command. *since Ant 1.8.0*

Comment: can you provide its usage example? I am not able to replicate it. I passed useSystemIn =true in sshexec task but it did not worked for me.

Comment: @PrerakTiwari Could you post what you tried in the question?

Comment: I just add the property "useSystemIn =true" in "executeOnLinux" given above.

Comment: @PrerakTiwari What version of Ant are you using? Is it above 1.9.4? You can run `ant -version` to determine that.

Comment: Yes its version 1.9.4 on Windows machine(from which I am executing the task) and version 1.6 on linux machine on which task is getting executed. I can not change the ant version there since it was supplied by WebSphere 8.5.

Comment: @PrerakTiwari Unfortunately I cannot reproduce that because I don't have access to an ssh server. Maybe you could also try the `input` attribute as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I don't know how to use it either and can not find any example demonstrating it. Can you share if you have something on using input attribute?